# why C doesn't have built-in conservative garbage collection in malloc

Tags: c, heap-memory

We know that memory leak is one of the most common/serious problems when writting C programs. I know it is the responsibility of programmers to free memory by calling `free()`, but it is still feasible to integrating a conservative garbage collector into malloc package.

[image]

Of course this garbage collector is **conservative** since C does not tag memory locations with type information (unlike Java's full-fledged garbage collector), there is no way for the collector in C to infer that the data is really an int e.g and not a pointer. Therefore, the allocator must conservatively mark a block as reachable, when in fact it might not be. But it is OK, it will still function correclty just not being able to free all unreachable blocks, it is better than nothing.

So why C doesn't have built-in conservative garbage collection in `malloc` to relieve programmers' burden?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222275/discussion-on-question-by-amjad-why-c-doesnt-have-built-in-conservative-garbage).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C is a language designed to be executed as efficiently as possible. It is used in a lot of performance-sensitive contexts such as kernels, embedded  and real-time systems.

Therefore, although this would be possible (and technically quite simple) to add a **dummy** Garbage Collector into C, this would deteriorate C's performance because it would require to store extra data to manage this GC (see for instance Java’s GC). Note though that it is not possible to make an entirely generic C GC due to pointer's arithmetic as pointed out by Jérôme Richard. A memory block can be never pointed and be still valid (due to indirect accesses, XOR-ing, ...)

Additionally, the memory management is not *that* complex in C and experienced C programmers rarely make such mistakes (double free, memory lost, read unitialized memory, ...). It has also to be noted that there is a lot of handful tools to debug C programs such as `valgrind` that allows to easily check the correctness of your memory accesses.

In conclusion if you need high level features such as a GC, C is just not the language for you. C allows very performant computing but its learning curve is quite steep and focuses more performance than user comfort

Answer (score 2):

Many people favour C because it *doesn't* have, or require, garbage collection. There are compiled languages with some similarity to C, like Go, that do have it. Most likely, these languages will increase in popularity. Certainly, GC is well-established in the Java world, and Java GC implementations are now quite powerful.

But they're not as powerful as writing code that doesn't need GC in the first place. To some extent, GC has increased in popularity because many of us are working in environments where it doesn't matter if our programs require hundreds of megabytes of memory. Memory is, after all, cheap these days.

With the rise of microservices, however, there's a renewed interest in memory-efficient implementations. It's hard to apply the term "micro" to anything that depends on GC.

It takes a certain amount of skill and time to manage your own memory as a developer. Not only that, languages like C are often unexpressive because of the volume of application code that is concerned with the minutiae of memory management. To some extent, that's just the price you have to pay for efficiency. There are many good memory analysis tools around, that hugely simplify the process of finding memory leaks in C code. If you're systematic, and know what you're doing, then there shouldn't be any memory leaks. But we're all only human, and it's good to know that there are such powerful tools for managing this problem.

In short, nobody who is systematic and methodical, and understands how C works, ought to be afraid of the lack of GC.

Answer (score 1):

Replacing the current `malloc` with a **tracing garbage collected `malloc` will break a lot of C codes**.
Indeed, being conservative is not sufficient for C codes to work properly. One reason is that a lot of C codes use pointer arithmetic/hacking to improve performance (eg. memory space, faster execution). One usual example is data structures holding a base 32-bits pointer with several relative 32-bits pointers useful to generate 64-bits pointers. Another example is pointer XORing although few code use that.

> it is better than nothing

Better in what way? Maybe in term of software engineering, but using a **tracing GC could dramatically decrease performance**. This is especially true on codes dealing with very big data structures with many pointers (eg. graphs/trees) on massively parallel architectures. One should keep in mind that C is also widely used on embedded systems where memory space is generally tight (without mentioning latency problems with GCs on such platforms).

Note that there are several existing libraries that providing conservative GC implementation in C (the most famous is probably the Boehm GC).